# Coffeescript inline vars definition

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How I can make inline vars definition? 
For example, next code in coffeescript:

```
a = "some..."
```

get this code in javascript

```
var a;

a = "some...";
```

But I want

```
var a="some..."
```

How I can make it?

Comment: Do your research! Check http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp for reference. In Coffeescript you don't even need the "var" keyword; http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-absolute-beginners-guide-to-coffeescript

Answer (score 0):

The coffeescript-to-javascript compiler guarantees the same semantics for all *.js files generated.

Functionally, you shouldn't need to worry about how the compilation works, let alone try to alter its behavior (which can often be very dangerous due to potential compiler bugs)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [official site](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope), declaring variables at the top of the closest scope is recommended in JavaScript. CoffeeScript undertakes the task and makes you not consider the issue so that you don't have to use `var`.

In most cases it is not matter, so you should let it be.